# Updating list in setUserVisibilityHint() method in a Fragment not working

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm using ViewPager & trying to update the listview everytime The ListFragment is shown to the user by overriding the setUserVisibilityHint()  method[the second last method in my code] in My listFragment but The code isn't working.
Here is a snippet of the List Fragment code :

```
public void showShoppinglist() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { testshop.TABLE_ROW_ID,
            testshop.TABLE_ROW_ONE, testshop.TABLE_ROW_TWO };
    Cursor cursor = testshop.db.query(testshop.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null,
            null, null, null);
      listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();//move the cursor to the first item
    if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        do {
            prepareListData(cursor);


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    //cursor.close(); // closing of the cursor
     // closing the database
}
/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */



public void prepareListData(final Cursor items) {


    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add(items.getString(1));


    // Adding child data
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("Born Sinner");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data

}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser){//saved my life
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        testshop.db = testshop.helper.getWritableDatabase();

             //fetch a cursor and update the listView from it   
             showShoppinglist();// this line doesn't work, List isnt't being
                                 // updated


        Log.d(getTag(), "WORKS LIKE A CHARM");//this line works
        }
    else{}
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    showShoppinglist();
    }

   }
```

tabadapter code:

```
package com.fragmment.adapter;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class tabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public tabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // add fragment activity
        return new addFragment();
    case 1:
        // list fragment activity
        return new ListFragment();
    case 2:
        //Alert fragment
        return new AlertFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}


}
```

Comment: The obvious question would be if you also let the adapter know about what changes you're doing. Right now, all I see you do in those methods is create new lists of data from a cursor and that's all.

Comment: How do I do that? Through adapter.notifySetDataChanged();? @Luksprog

Comment: I don't know how you implemented the adapter. Most likely you made of copy of those lists and then use them in the adapter so `notifydataSetChanged()` will most not work. If this is the case you'll need to assing the new list of data to those list used by the adapter and then call `notifydataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Would you write this as an answer in Detail so i could accept it. You know,Help others with same Problem? @Luksprog

Comment: Was this the reason for your problem? Above I made an assumption about what you're doing.

Comment: Too bad it did't work. I'm trying to refresh a listview from a DB in a Fragment each time the said Fragment is swiped to or viewed by the user i.e Each time the user swipes to the Fragment it updates/refereshes from the DB. notifydataSetChanged() seemed like it would work but didn't :(. Would you know of any fix like this or anywhere I can find a Good tutorial for this? @Luksprog

Comment: Can you post your adapter's code? You didn't understood my comment from above.

Comment: I posted my adapter's code.  @Luksprog